# Content Query Web Part - No Results

Tags: content-query-web-part

How can I setup the display for a content query web part when no results are returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the OuterTemplate.Empty XSLT template in the ContentQueryMain.xsl file. This template displays a message only when the web part is in edit mode but you can modify the XSL to display it even when it is in run-mode. Check this out:

http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/displaying-a-customizable-message-when-content-query-web-part-returns-no-result/

http://johnnyharbieh.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/how-to-display-a-message-when-no-results-are-returned-by-the-content-by-query-web-part-cbqwp/